# Can I turn css keyframes animation into video/movie/mpg?

Tags: html, css, animation

I recently made a simple but cool animated banner with CSS's "**@keyframes**"...

...but since that animation apparently demands a lot of power, it gives me a very choppy/sluggish web browser (Chrome) as well as turning my Macbook Pro into an expensive hair dryer, is there any way to render an animation of this kind into a movie instead?

Of course I could take a live screenshot with my video program but then I still get the choppiness, which is not desired. 
Or is there any other way to actually make it smooth/remove the sluggishness so I can record my screen?

OBSERVE:

- I'm not using HTML5's "canvas" element like some other people around stackoverflow are using.
- The speed of the animation is exactly where I want it. The speed of the animation is fast enough to run smoothly, but also slow enough to sometimes present the choppy behavior here and there (which proves that the speed is not to blame).
- GIF is out of the question!! That worked in the 90s...not anymore! I have way too many colors in the animated image.

Part of HTML code:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="imgA1" src="galaxy.jpg">
    <img class="imgB1" src="logo.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Part of CSS code:

```
.imgA1{
  animation-duration: 100s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.imgA1{
  animation-name: containerA;
}
@keyframes containerA {
  0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
  25%  {background-color:yellow; left:0px; top:-483px;}
  26%  {background-color:blue; left:0px; top:-483px;}
  50%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:0px;}
  51%  {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
  75%  {background-color:blue; left:0px; top:-483px;}
  76%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:-483px;}
  99%  {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
  100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

Peace folks!

Comment: How is **this** animation turning your Macbook Pro into a hair dryer?

Comment: Had a feeling this question would come :D Because the keyframes animation is somewhat heavy on my cpu and the cpu fan just panics.

Comment: There's no reason it should perform badly. You could either animate by hand with Adobe Premiere/After Effects or record with a WebM screen recorder (would suggest making the animation 300 seconds then speeding up the video 3×).

Comment: @moller.peter you have a very basic animation going on. If **this** animation is challenging your Mackbook Pro, I'd probably get a new one. Aaaaaand possibly some life insurance because it looks like you have a ticking time bomb on your hands.

Comment: Well thanks for the feedback guys! I guess I'll swipe my mac back to scratch and see if it helps. Main thing is that I don't want people to have the same issue once I post it on my web site. If problem persists, I'll come back here, thanks!